# What does this to in python super().__init__(**kwargs)

Tags: python

I know that super is used to call the **init** method in the superclass, I'm having trouble understanding what kwargs does I know it takes key arguments

what does it do here?

```
class LoginScreen(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text = "Username: "))
        self.username = TextInput(multiline = False)
        self.add_widget(self.username)

        self.add_widget(Label(text="Password: "))
        self.username = TextInput(multiline=False, password=True)
        self.add_widget(self.username)

        self.add_widget(Label(text="Two Factor Auth: "))
        self.tffa = TextInput(multiline=False, password=True)
        self.add_widget(self.tffa)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \*\* (double star) and \* (star) do for parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-parameters)

Answer (score 13):

- `def __init__(self, **kwargs):` packs all of the keyword arguments used in any given call to `__init__` into a `dict`
- `super().__init__(**kwargs):` expands them into keyword arguments again.

It's like a wildcard for function parameters. It can be a lazy way to give the subclass the same parameter signature as the parent without bothering to type all of the possible keyword parameters in again.

Just grab them as a blob and shovel them off to the parent to figure out.

Answer (score 4):

For example you put this :

```
x = LoginScreen(size=1, blahblah=2, something=3)
```

We have now:

```
>>> print(kwargs)
{'size': 1, 'blahblah': 2, 'something': 3}
```

So if it reaches the following line: `super().__init__(**kwargs)`
it will be equal to that : `super().__init__(size=1, blahblah=2, something=3)`

**Becarefully:** if you didn't put double asterisks "**" it will be equal to one argument as key:

```
`super().__init__({'size': 1, 'blahblah': 2, 'something': 3})`
```

And you can also use it like that:

```
options = [1,2,3]
def func(first=None, second=None, last=None):
    print("first arg:", first)
    print("second arg:", second)
    print("third arg:", last)

func(*options)
```

Here we use one asterisk since this is a list not a dict so that means expand the options list for each argument, the output will be:

```
first arg: 1
second arg: 2
third arg: 3
```

But if we call options without the asterisk.

```
func(options)
```

See what's gonna happen:

```
first arg: [1, 2, 3]
second arg: None
third arg: None
```

The samething with kwargs except they go like that:

```
fuction(key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3, ...)
```